# Ordinary differential equation in the plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $V(x,y) = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}, \frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}\right)$ is a vector field in the plane.

Can its integral curve (t) through an arbitrary initial condition (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>) be expressed explicitly in terms of familiar functions? I.e., '(t) = V((t)) for all t, with (0) = (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>).

Comment: did you want a multiple of $(x,-y)$ or the more common $(-y,x) \; ?$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the initial position of our particle $(x_0,y_0)$ belongs in the first quadrant, $\mathbb{Q}_1$. If $(x(t),y(t))$ is the position of the particle at time $t$, it's not hard to see that $x(t)y(t)=x_0y_0$. In other words, our trajectory $(x(t),y(t))$ is bounded to the portion of the hyperbola $xy=x_0y_0$ that's contained in $\mathbb{Q}_1$. This means $x(t)$ must satisfy the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+x^2+x_0^2y_0^2}}$$ Unless you're able to solve this DE for $x(t)$ explicitly, I don't see how you'll be able to express the trajectory for $x(t)$ in terms of familiar functions. Wolfram produces a [nasty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B9%29%2Fx%5E2) expression for $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^4+x^2+x_0^2y_0^2}}{x^2}dx$ when we consider $(x_0,y_0)=(3,1)$.